# Pull record between 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

table1

```
ID    VendorID    
100   11190       
200   99999
```

table2

```
ID    VendorID     
100   11190          
100   11190           
200   12523        
200   53266
```

My expect result and my goal if ID and VendorID from table1 match with ID and VendorID from table2  then flag  NO

```
table1ID    table1Vendor    table2ID    table2Vendor    Code
100         12345           100         12345           No
100         12345           100         12345           No
100         12345           100         45678           No
200         56489           200         11111           Use
200         56489           200         22222           Use
```

My query

```
SELECT a.id as table1ID, a.vendorid as table1Vendor, b.id as table2ID, b.Vendorid as table2Vendor
    , case
    when a.vendorid <> b.Vendorid
    then 'Use' else 'No'
    end as Code
FROM table_1 a
JOIN table_2 b  on a.id = b.id
```

But I got

```
table1ID    table1Vendor    table2ID    table2Vendor    Code
100         12345           100         12345           No
100         12345           100         12345           No
100         12345           100         45678           Use
200         56489           200         11111           Use
200         56489           200         22222           Use
```

You can see row 3 is incorrect, should code as NO cause 12345(table1vendor) still match with 12345(table2vendor)

Not sure why, need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking the same row for a match, but according to your logic you need to check all rows, therefore you need another sub-query.

```
SELECT a.ID AS table1ID, a.VendorID AS table1Vendor, b.ID AS table2ID, b.VendorID as table2Vendor
  , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 b1 WHERE b1.id = a.ID AND b1.VendorID = a.VendorID) THEN 'No' ELSE 'Use' END AS Code
FROM table_1 a
JOIN table_2 b ON a.ID = b.ID;
```